# Running a JAR multiple times with concurrent requests

Tags: java, multithreading, jar, java-7

I have a JAR that uses the new WatchService API to monitor a folder for uploads. Currently, when I execute the JAR, it detects the first upload, does it's task, exits but never runs again even with more uploads coming in. I want my JAR to run permanently, so every time an upload happens the task gets run but the JAR still checks for new uploads and will run the tasks on them also.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: any webservice must be running on some server... like apache tomcat, jboss etc.. the servlet container should handle multiple request effectively without you doing much tinkering with the code. Basically you should use the servlet container to handle request and service then via your jar.

Comment: @Matt Please show us your code you have written so far!

Comment: @MarcelHöll, can we talk in chat?

Comment: @Matt Okay...in Java Chat...

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop. I assume you have a Main method that that it executes once. You need to build a mechanism that this action repeats until some command is received to stop.